# JSON PHP data returning null

Tags: php, json

I am trying to fetch a PHP script using AJAX and return the values as JSON. For some reason, my script fails and I am trying to figure out the problem. When I enter a value from the database into the address bar, like:

```
www.someaddress/post.php?kinaseEntry=aValue
```

I get a JSON output like so:

```
{"kinaseSKU":null,"url":null,"molecularWeight":null,"tracerSKU":null,"antiSKU1":"antiSKU1","antiSKU2":"antiSKU2","bufferSKU":"bufferSKU","tracerConc":null,"assayConc":null}
```

My PHP file looks like so:

```
<?php

//Include connection to database
require_once 'connect.php';

$kinase = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST["kinaseEntry"]);

mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); 

$findKinase = "SELECT * FROM kbaData where cleanSKU = '" .$kinase. "' ";

if ($result = mysql_query($findKinase)) {

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    $kinaseSKU = $row['cleanSKU'];
    $url = $row['url'];
    $molecularWeight = $row['molecularWeight'];
    $tracerSKU = $row['tracerSKU'];
    $antiSKU1 = $row['antiSKU1'];
    $antiSKU2 = $row['antiSKU2'];
    $bufferSKU = $row['bufferSKU'];
    $tracerConc = $row['tracerConc'];
    $assayConc = $row['assayConc'];


    /* JSON ROW */
    $json = array ("kinaseSKU" => $kinaseSKU, "url" => $url, "molecularWeight" => $molecularWeight, "tracerSKU" => $tracerSKU, "antiSKU1" => $antiSKU1, "antiSKU2" => $antiSKU2, "bufferSKU" => $bufferSKU, "tracerConc" => $tracerConc, "assayConc" => $assayConc );

} else  {

    /* CATCH ANY ERRORS */
    $json = array('error' => 'Mysql Query Error');
}

/* SEND AS JSON */
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

/* RETURN JSON */
echo json_encode($json);

/* STOP SCRIPT */
exit;
?>
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? Or have I done this wrong?

EDIT: Here is my jQuery/Ajax that calls the PHP script:

```
$(document).ready(function()    {

$('#kinaseEntry').change(function ()    {

    var kinaseEntry = $('#kinaseEntry').val();
    var dataString = 'kinaseEntry' + kinaseEntry;

    $('#waiting').show(500);
    $('#message').hide(0);
    alert(kinaseEntry);

    //Fetch list from database
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "post.php",
        datatype: "json",
        data:   dataString,
        success : function(datas)   {
            alert("datas" + datas);
        },
        error : function(error) {
            alert("Oops, there was an error!");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Did you `var_dump($row)` to be sure it isn't all NULLs? Your code looks correct otherwise.

Comment: @sberry The failure is in the question title - JSON is all null values...

Comment: $findKinase returns only a single row, or is it possible, that you get more than one row back ? Looks like you're missing a loop there.

Comment: when i use var_dump($row) I get bool(false)

Comment: @methemer i'm only wanting to return the data of a single entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I am not sure if `if (isset($_POST['kinaseEntry']))` will work for what you have shown. The URL you have shown is a get request, so if you want access to that variable you will have to use `$_GET['kinaseEntry']`. If you need to do POST change the method attribute in your form to `<form method="POST">` that will give you the post variable.

Comment: i remove the isset feature when testing

Comment: you were indeed correct. After mashing my code with some of the examples provided here, the last thing i changed was the POST to GET and it now returns the values as it should. Thanks to all who took the time to answer my problem

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql_query` function returns a true value even if 0 rows are returned. It returns false only when there was a database error. So i believe it executes a query and there are no results, so there are `null` values in the JSON. Try to use mysql_num_rows:

```
$findKinase = "SELECT * FROM kbaData where cleanSKU = '" .$kinase. "' ";

if ($result = mysql_query($findKinase)) {
      $json = array('error' => 'Mysql Query Error');
}else{
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($num_rows > 0){
         // Do sth with the results
    }else{
         $json = array('error' => 'No results');
    }
}
```

Comment: have tried this fix, unfortunately i get >{"error":"Mysql Query Error"} back

Comment: So you have error in the query. You can display the error using [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php).

Comment: sorry that message was intended for another member, i will try your solution just now

Comment: have tried your example, but unfortunately i am getting a blank screen with no results

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that there wasn't actually a row returned from your query.  Try:

```
$result = mysql_query($findKinase);
if ($result !== false && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // your code
}
```

`$result` is `false` in this case if there was an error in the query.  If there was no error, then check to see if there were actually rows returned.  If there **were** more than 0 rows returned, **then** attempt to extract data.

Comment: @JPK I don't think that's unfortunate, I think that means the problem isn't where you thought it was.  You need to debug your actual query now.  =)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're getting back an array of rows, so that doesn't really work as you'd expect it to.  This should fix it, but I don't think it is the best approach (but I think it should work anyway).

```
$kinase = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST["kinaseEntry"]);

mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); 

$findKinase = "SELECT * FROM kbaData where cleanSKU = '" .$kinase. "' , LIMIT 0,1";

if ($result = mysql_query($findKinase)) {

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    $kinaseSKU = $row[0]['cleanSKU'];
    $url = $row[0]['url'];
    $molecularWeight = $row[0]['molecularWeight'];
    $tracerSKU = $row[0]['tracerSKU'];
    $antiSKU1 = $row[0]['antiSKU1'];
    $antiSKU2 = $row[0]['antiSKU2'];
    $bufferSKU = $row[0]['bufferSKU'];
    $tracerConc = $row[0]['tracerConc'];
    $assayConc = $row[0]['assayConc'];


    /* JSON ROW */
    $json = array ("kinaseSKU" => $kinaseSKU, "url" => $url, "molecularWeight" => $molecularWeight, "tracerSKU" => $tracerSKU, "antiSKU1" => $antiSKU1, "antiSKU2" => $antiSKU2, "bufferSKU" => $bufferSKU, "tracerConc" => $tracerConc, "assayConc" => $assayConc );

} else  {

    /* CATCH ANY ERRORS */
    $json = array('error' => 'Mysql Query Error');
}

/* SEND AS JSON */
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

/* RETURN JSON */
echo json_encode($json);

/* STOP SCRIPT */
exit;
```